# Chart.js not showing data until I click on the label 3 times

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm adding a chart in a website and I'm having a weird issue with chart.js. I'm loading the data from 2 arrays that are created when the page is loaded from a json file.

The issue is that the data it's not showing until I click on the label of the chart 2 times. At load, there is no info, 1st click x labels are showing up and in 2nd click both, x labels and data are showing up. After that, clicking on the label of the dataset work as expected.

I assumed my problem was that I was loading the data before the chart exists, so, my idea was to encapsulate everything in a function and call it when clicking a button that shows the chart, but it's keeping doing the same thing. How would you fix it?

Here is my html related code:

```
<div class="popup">
    <span class="popuptrend" id="myPopup"><canvas id="myChart" width="auto" height="400"></canvas></span>
</div>
```

And my JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#showTrend").click(function(){
        createChart();
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    });
});
function createChart(){
    var labels = [];
    var dataValue = [];

    $.getJSON("./resources/chart.json", function(jsonData) {
        var index = 0;
        for (var key in jsonData) {
                if(index == 0){ // SKIP FISRT ITEM
                    index++;
                }else{
                    labels.push(key);
                    dataValue.push(parseFloat(jsonData[key]));
                }
        }
    });
    var dataVar = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets:
        [{
            label: "Value",
            backgoundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
            borderWith: 1,
            data: dataValue
        }]
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: dataVar,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And a extract from my data json file:

```
{
    "15/04/2017":"67.34375",
    "16/04/2017":"67.3203125",
}
```

And a [gif of the behaviour](http://g.recordit.co/Ix7Nlo7SI4.gif).
Thanks!

Comment: Try to create chart `new Chart` when you have responce from getJSON.

Comment: try encapsulating the whole thing on the done() callback of `getJSON` like this: `$.getJSON(...).done(var dataVar....)` (I can't test it now for you, let me know the results please)

Comment: It worked, thanks both of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [**`$.getJSON()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method is asynchronous, you should construct your chart inside it­*'s* callback function, like so :

```
...
$.getJSON("./resources/chart.json", function(jsonData) {
   var index = 0;
   for (var key in jsonData) {
      if (index == 0) { // SKIP FISRT ITEM
         index++;
      } else {
         labels.push(key);
         dataValue.push(parseFloat(jsonData[key]));
      }
   }

   var dataVar = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: "Value",
         backgoundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
         borderWith: 1,
         data: dataValue
      }]
   };

   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: dataVar,
      options: {
         scales: {
            yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
               }
            }]
         }
      }
   });
});
...
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

Comment: It worked. Maybe to make it easier to understand it's better to put it under a a .done function as suggested in the comments of the answer, but this works as expected.

Comment: um.. yes, you can put it under `done` or even `then`.. basically all are the same :)

Comment: I know, but since this is a large web app and maybe I will (or others) be doing maintenance in the future, I'm trying to make it as easier to understand for every one

Answer (score 1):

As I posted before as a comment, try doing like this:

```
$.getJSON(...).done(var dataVar....)
```